# Chrome give "Your connection is not private" when using with a proxy

Tags: google-chrome, jmeter

I'm trying to record a test with Jmeter for https://maps.google.com using JMeter's Test script recorder proxy. However I got "Your connection is not private" error and it doesn't show "proceed to https://maps.google.com" option like usual

[image: Error without "proceed to the https://maps.google.com" option]

Anyone knows how to proceed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest to reconsider the whole test scenario as:

1. Leave Google Maps load testing to Google engineers
2. If you attempt to launch a load test against Google Maps - you'll get banned.
3. Even if your application uses Google Maps in frame for something - you should exclude it from scope as it isn't something you can control even if you won't be happy with the performance.

Just in case if you still need it for any reason you can try the following workarounds:

1. Under `chrome://settings/`

   - Pricacy -> Clear browser data
   - HTTPS/SSL - > Uninstall JMeter certificate
2. Try using less "paranoid" browser i.e.[Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) which uses its own certificates and proxy settings
3. There is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test which doesn't not require setting up proxies and worrying about SSL certificates - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)

Answer (score 0):

Your ip is being changed multiple times due to the proxy so it's making Google think a hacker is ip spoofing a site. Just change the `https://` in the url to `http://`.

Comment: Thanks Neonz27. I tried "http" and it redirected to "https". So the error still the same

Comment: Oh I just read on an article that Google no longer supports non-encrypted urls.

Comment: So that means it's now down to somehow getting your browser to allow https. :/ Sorry I can't be of much help beyond that, because I don't use JMeter and normally my proxies are using proxychains in Linux.